# Date Picker CSS not loading properly

Tags: javascript, css

I have created a date picker for solar date with javascript. The date picker loading very well when I load it only with its own css file, but if I add the date picker in any application than the alignment of the date picker is not showing properly.

What should I do to force the div created javascript to select its own css properties.
OR
how should I load the CSS file after the javascript file is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter when you load the CSS (ideally you should load the CSS in the head section to avoid "blink" effect) but once it's loaded, the date picker should be displayed properly.

I guess the reason why it's not is because some other styles are overriding it? Worth checking with document inspector.

I'd strongly recommend to put all CSS in a file but alternatively you could apply some inline CSS using javascript.

It would really help if you could give us jsfiddle.

Comment: Well, I have some problem with jsfiddle, but here a image: http://s21.postimg.org/ov5bepi93/dtp.jpg

Comment: Looks like something is overriding it but I can't really help you until I see the code, I guess you don't have public link to your project, do you?